# Is an activity calling action in an activity considered finished only when the called activity terminates and reaches its activity end node?

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

Assuming we have two activities; activity_1 and activity_2 with an action (action_A) present in activity_1 that invokes activity_2, is action_A considered done/finished only when the invoked activity_2 terminates and reaches its activity end node? Or is action_A considered done once it starts activity_2 and both activities run independently (activity_1 continues running while activity_2 runs as well)?

Comment: It would definitely help if you come up with the according AD.

Comment: Actually this isn't about a specific actual AD. The question was actually hypothetical. I can draw an AD to better clarify the question once I get access to my PC. Anyway, bruno has already understood what I meant and has provided a great detailed answer. Thanks Thomas!

Comment: Even for a hypothetical question a diagram would make sense (since UML offers diagramming it's meant for helping to transport the message). Just remember that for the next time. Bruno isn't as impatient as me. But happy to see that he got the point! Btw. you're talking about activity invocations which is just a bit more of the story that Bruno explains...

Comment: You're absolutely right. I'll keep that in mind onwards. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I well understand your action is a call action

From the [formal/17-12-05](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF) § 16.3.3.1 page 451 : a CallAction may result in either a synchronous or asynchronous Behavior invocation, either directly or through an Operation call.

- If the call is synchronous ( isSynchronous =true), then the execution of the Action does not complete until the execution of the invoked Behavior completes, normally or otherwise. (If the Behavior execution does not complete normally but, instead, raises an exception, then that exception is propagated out of the CallAction, (see sub clauses 15.5.3 and 16.13 on exceptions and how they are handled).
- If the call is asynchronous ( isSynchronous =false), then the execution of the Action completes as soon as the Behavior has been invoked. When an asynchronous call is complete, execution of the Behavior containing the
  CallAction proceeds independently of and concurrently with the execution of the invoked Behavior, including the handling of any exceptional conditions that occur while the Behavior is executing.

> is action_A considered done/finished only when the invoked activity_2 terminates and reaches its activity end node?

yes if the call is synchronous ( more the case of an exception )

> Or is action_A considered done once it starts activity_2 and both activities run independently (activity_1 continues running while activity_2 runs as well)

in that case the call is asynchronous so the execution of the action completes as soon as the activity_2  has been invoked without waiting the end of the activity_2

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer and the reference. This makes perfect sense to me! I appreciate you taking the time to clear this out. Thanks!